# Telegram API vs Bot API

Tags: api, bots, difference, telegram

Can you help me understand the differences for Telegram API vs Bot API please, I tried telegram website but just get confused?

Thanks
Ramin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Telegram APIs**

> This API allows you to build your own customized Telegram clients. It is 100% open for all developers who wish to create Telegram applications on our platform. Feel free to study the open source code of existing Telegram applications for examples of how things work here. Don't forget to register your application in our system.

**Bot API**

> This API allows you to connect bots to our system. Telegram Bots are special accounts that do not require an additional phone number to set up. These accounts serve as an interface for code running somewhere on your server.

You can create Telegram client apps with your own UI and environment using Telegram APIs (to communicate with Telegram server). like [Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.plus&hl=en), [Telegram Web](https://web.telegram.org/), Mobogram.

But the Telegram Bot API is not about the UI and environment. It's about the possible services in the Telegram platform. Then users communicate with your Bot and get any services via their original Telegram apps (or their Telegram Clients). [Game bot](https://telegram.me/gamebot), [English Learning bot](https://telegram.me/AndyRobot).

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, can you help me understand if I want to develop mobile apps (Android/iOS etc) and broadcast messages to them from my server but I want my server just talk to one API? if so is it Bot API or Telegram API? What also happens for those messages inside the telegram (I mean if they are going to be cached to some time or so)?

Comment: @RaminRabii Do you want to just broardcast messages to users inside telegram, and they receive your messages inside their telegram? Or are you planning to create an app that has to be installed separately inside iphone or android?

Comment: I am studying both scenarios.

Comment: @RaminRabii you can use bot of them in your scenario but be aware that creating a Telegram client is more complex and more difficult.
You can use Bot API. Simply Telegram send user messages via Webhook to your server. Server make its own process on user messages and send reply message via Webhook to the Telegram and Telegram give it to the user
.

Comment: I have got lot of example of  Bot API and not a single of Telegram APIs, could someone help me to get the Telegram APIs, I want to develop a custom web page and want to use API to send messages to my telegram contacts, I don;t want to use Bots