# How to send individual message to a specific phone number via Telegram like a SMS (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram

I'm developping an application that have to send messages to my users, so I chose the Telegram because it is popular and easy to use. I'm new in development to Telegram and I need some directions.

So, each user have this application installed in a PC, it have a config window where the user can register the phone number, email and some personal info. Also, this software stays ON all day long and when some events happens it must send alerts to the user's phone (like SMS), and this is my problem, I don't know which approach is better, using the normal Telegram API or a bot. I have no idea how to start this.

Is the Telegram a good choice? Is possible to send a message when I have just the phone number? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer on [Telegram API vs Bot API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942771/telegram-api-vs-bot-api). I generally agree to use Telegram as a media of notification system if it's not possible for you to install your own App on user phones and create your own notification. On another hand, if you have the resource, you can use traditional method such as SMS and Call for notification.

Comment: I have no resources to develop a phone App, so, I have to use something like Telegram. I read a lot about the Telegram API but is not clear if is possible to send a message to someone if I have only the phone number. Is it possible?

Comment: @GustavoE.Hennemann As far as I know, this is not possible. You have to ask your user to contact(start conversation) with your bot  first. Then you can send message to the user. This is understandable because if bot can send message freely by phone numbers, your telegram will be filled by junk message