# How to send large files through Telegram Bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I've been working on a bot that would send users videos (mostly larger than 500mb).
I've read the telegram bot api docs. There is a restriction of **50MB**, with videos/animations/documents.
In the recent changes, Telegram announced now bots can send files upto 2000 MB.

I'm using **Python Telegram Bot** wrapper. I've tried to send videos using both from direct url and from directory. But it fails and shows the file size limitation error.
I also tried with get requests to Telegram Bot API. It failed.

There are many bots that are uploading files upto **2GB**, So, my question is how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @valijon in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52315151/6328506) you could also try to send files through InputStream, http url and cached file IDs. Also, I'd recommend you to take a look at [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/):

```
# Keep track of the progress while uploading
def progress(current, total):
    print(f"{current * 100 / total:.1f}%")

app.send_video("me", "video.mp4", progress=progress)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could upload 2gb files with telegram-bot-Api(a git hub repository),here is a link to it:
https://github.com/tdlib/telegram-bot-api#usage
You must first setup a Telegram Bot API server and run it locally.After that you can run your botfather telegram bot and upload large files.
For reference,view this vid:
https://youtu.be/z2CjMIZEpEU